# Develop a service which is able to listen on tcp port for data in .net

Tags: wcf, service, tcp

Here is my scenario:

I want to develop a program that listens a TCP port for incoming XML data and after processing it, save it in sql server database. I have a wcf service which can process the xml data and save it in sql server database. Now I want a program (maybe a windows service or something) which can listen the TCP port for data and call my wcf service method by passing that xml data as an argument or a single service(windows or wcf) which can listen the port for data as well as process it and insert it in the Sql server database.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

host the WCF service in a windows service
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A WCF Service can listen to TCP port using netTCPBinding. Here are some samples that will help you configure your service over TCP

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752250(v=vs.90).aspx

the second part of your question is unclear. do you want a windows service to host the WCF or to call WCF?

If you want host the WCF service in windows service, then use a ServiceHost
If you want to call it, just create a service reference in you windows service project

Comment: I want to call the wcf service from windows service, I have added the reference to windows serivce and also the proxy classes generated but when I am calling it it is giving exception of "EndPoint Configuration", I dont know how to configure the App.config of Windows Service

Comment: can you append the code that you wrote in Windows service as part of your question. For adding config file to your windows service simply add a new item and you should see app.config as an option there